# Why are sed and perl not parsing file with < characters?

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I am trying to populate some XML fields to give myself a headstart on a large chunk of manual data entry I'm performing.

I'm trying to use regex and 2 flat files to turn text like this:

```
EA10A3
```

Into this:

```
<nodevice id="EA10A3" seq=" " />
```

Here's what is happening with sed:

```
~/Tickets/RWSP-11422 > cat locations.txt
EA10A1
EA10A2
EA10A3

~/Tickets/RWSP-11422 > cat platform
  <nodevice id="PPPPPP" seq=" " />

~/Tickets/RWSP-11422 > while read i; do cat platform | sed "s/PPPPPP/$i/g"; done <locations.txt
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A1
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A2
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A3
```

And the same thing with Perl:

```
~/Tickets/RWSP-11422 > while read i; do cat platform | perl -wpl -e "s/PPPPPP/$i/g"; done < locations.txt
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A1
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A2
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A3
```

Why am I getting

```
" seq=" " />ice id="EA10A1
```

instead of

```
<nodevice id="EA10A1" seq=" " />
```

?

And how can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `locations.txt` has DOS line endings (`\r\n`) rather than UNIX line endings (`\n`). When a carriage return `\r` is printed the cursor moves to the beginning of the line, causing jumbled output.

You can verify this with `cat -v`, which prints the carriage returns as `^M`.

```
$ cat -v locations.txt
EA10A1^M
EA10A2^M
EA10A3^M
$ while read i; do cat platform | sed "s/PPPPPP/$i/g"; done < locations.txt | cat -v
  <nodevice id="EA10A1^M" seq=" " />
  <nodevice id="EA10A2^M" seq=" " />
  <nodevice id="EA10A3^M" seq=" " />
```

Run `locations.txt` through `dos2unix` or `fromdos` to fix it.

```
$ dos2unix locations.txt
dos2unix: converting file blah.txt to Unix format ...
$ cat -v locations.txt
EA10A1
EA10A2
EA10A3
$ while read i; do cat platform | sed "s/PPPPPP/$i/g"; done < locations.txt | cat -v
  <nodevice id="EA10A1" seq=" " />
  <nodevice id="EA10A2" seq=" " />
  <nodevice id="EA10A3" seq=" " />
```

Comment: Thanks for the more verbose answer.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You're getting

`<nodevice id="EA10A1^M" seq=" " />`

because your input file contains

`EA10A1^M^J`

Fix your input file with (e.g.) `dos2unix`.

(**^M** represents a carriage return, and **^J** represents a line feed.)

Comment: You might also need to escape " (\") in platform.

Comment: @Phil Perry, huh? no. It's the locations are that are being interpolated into the Perl code.

Comment: Are you talking about escaping to `&quot;`?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a `dos2unix` issue for me. Try running

```
 dos2unix locations.txt
 perl -ne 'chomp ; printf ("<nodevice id=\"$_\" seq=\" \" / > \n");' locations.txt
```